# Updating a nested many-to-many

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Serializer that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 97, 
    "categories": [
        23,
        18
    ], 
},
```

Where categories is a `many-to-many` on my model. I don't want a nested view just IDs so I used a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`. So this works only if I have `read_only=True` which I don't want.

```
Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, or set read_only=`True`.
```

I want to run each id and add them like this to the model....

```
class ItemsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)


    def create(self, validated_data):

        categories = validated_data.pop('categories')
        instance = Items.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ID in categories:
            add to model
            cat_instance = category.objects.get(id=ID)
            then add to cat_instance etc
```

How is this possible as `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` want me to use ready only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to subclass `ModelSerializer` instead of `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` and then supply the queryset argument for the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`:

```
 categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True,
                                                 queryset=Categories.objects.all())
```